# Prevent AirPlay from sleeping

Tags: ios, objective-c, airplay

I have an app that uses AirPlay. I am using the iPad to present data on a TV. The user sets up the demo and then puts the device down and the app should take care of updating the TV even in the background state. The app is processing data in the background and I can see it is always being updated. However the AirPlay disconnects after a few minutes if nothing on the screen changes.

How can I prevent AirPlay from disconnecting?

Note: 
I am not streaming video or audio. I am only presenting data using views.

Update:

After more twiddling I found that the background task dies after 10 minutes and that is when the screen dies. I tried to play a sound like https://stackoverflow.com/a/15732710/1449607 described but the AirPlay still disconnected. I am now toggling a pixel and now it seems that the screen is staying connect. There must be a better solution for displaying slowly updating data to AirPlay.

Comment: Guessing. May be it is somehow related to mDNS cache invalidation ? You may try to use 'mDNSClientPosix' tool from Apple's open source mDNSResponder library to poll network for airplay services. Run it periodically to force Apple TV to announce its services. It is not a solution though, but if it works, maybe you should investigate more on your network environment.

Comment: I am able to connect to airplay. The screen only sleeps if the data on the screen does not change.